# How to do concurrent insertion in a linear probing hash table?

Tags: multithreading, hashtable

I'm trying to write a multithread linear probing hash table. There's a deadlock problem that I don't know how to resolve.

Suppose the hash table has two pages, each with a number of buckets. Two threads want to insert simultaneously. The first thread found a tombstone in page 1, and the second thread found a tombstone in page 2. But before the threads make the insertion, they both need to check whether the key is already existing in the hash table. If the key exists, the insertion is supposed to fail immediately.

In my current implementation, each thread holds the write lock on the page it is going to write, then tries to acquire the read lock on other pages. So thread 1 tries to acquire read lock on page 2 (whose write lock is held by thread 2), and thread 2 tries to acquire read lock on page 1 (whose write lock is held by thread 1). This results in a deadlock.

What's the proper way to implement concurrent insertion in linear probing hash table?

Comment: The trick to avoiding deadlocks is to make sure that either your threads never acquire more than one lock at a time, or if they must do so, then to make sure they all acquire the locks in the same order.